# Bitbucket Pull Request Jenkins Job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, bitbucket, refspec

I want to trigger a job in Jenkins whenever a pull request is created in Bitbucket. I have used **Bitbucket Pull Request Builde**r for this and set up the refspec and branch specifier as follow:

1. **Refspec**: `+refs/pull/*/head:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*`
2. **Branch Specifier**: `pr/*/from`

But Jenkins job is picking the last merged branch not the source branch of the open pull request.

[image]

> Please help me with this or provide me with a clean solution to create
>   a pipeline to trigger a job whenever a pull request is created in
>   Jenkins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prefer [Generic+Webhook+Trigger+Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Generic+Webhook+Trigger+Plugin) instead of BitBucket it provides everything in the payload when pull request created.

[image]

Here are the steps

- Create Webhook in [Bitbucket](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/manage-webhooks-735643732.html) 
  [image]
- add Your Jenkins Remote URL in the webhook
  [image]
- Handle payload on Jenkins side using Generic Webhook 
  [image]

You can check details integration [here](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Generic+Webhook+Trigger+Plugin)

Comment: Glad to know :), you can check the whole payload in the link provided.

Comment: Yeah I followed the plugin github page and used the suggested variables and it worked like a charm, didn't knew about this plugin